# Show post title words one by one

Tags: title, get-the-title

How to show post title words one by one, but to exclude words with 3 or less characters.
Also it would be nice to be able to exclude some words, for example to make some list of words to exclude from showing.

Point is to show post title words one one but to exclude common words with 3 or less characters such as: the, is, at, and, on, it... And also to have option to make list of any unwanted words.

This is what I have so far, it gets title words, one by one, but without excluding any word.

```
<?php
$title = get_the_title();
$parts = explode( ' ', $title );
echo $parts[0];
echo $parts[1];
echo $parts[2];
//...
?>
```

Comment: How is this a WordPress question and not a general PHP array/string manipulation question? What WordPress specific expertise is needed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function in functions.php to see if your title part is in an array of 'banned' words:

```
function check_word( $word )
{
    $blacklist = array('the', 'it', 'and', ...);

    if ( !in_array( $word, $blacklist ) && strlen( $word ) > 3 ) {
      return $word;
    }
    else {
      return '';
    }
}
```

Run your title words through it.  It'll only print a word if it's not in the blacklist.

```
$title = get_the_title();
$parts = explode( ' ', $title );
echo check_word( $parts[0] );
echo check_word( $parts[1] );
echo check_word( $parts[2] );
```

Tweak to taste.

Comment: When I add that function it breaks my template. Could you please look at it again?

Comment: You should post your template

Comment: @user1038179 did you use the function verbatim?  If so, it WILL break your template.  You have to update the `$blacklist` array to contain the words you want to exclude.

Comment: The code in the answer was missing a `)` in the `if()` statement, too; I've fixed that.

Comment: Now it is working, it is not breaking theme anymore. But, it shows excluded words only (blacklist words) and it is not showing any non blacklisted word. It should work opposite.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the fixed code.

Comment: Thank you @Dan Bough Could you make function to exclude words with 3 or less characters too? Writing all common possible words to exclude will take time... So having option to automatically exclude words with 3 or less characters with option to exclude any other word on list would be great.

Comment: @user1038179 Answer updated to include string length check.

Comment: @DanBough Can you tweak this to include some words with 3 characters. For example whitelist (red, man, boy...)? Thanks.